# How to define PTM_RATIO according to iOS device

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I'm using Cocos2D+Box2D for my game development. As Box2D uses meters instead of pixels, I need to define a pixels-to-meters ratio. So I define a PTM_RATIO at the top of my code:

```
define PTM_RATIO 32
```

But 32 is fine for iPhone<5, for the other devices I need to set different number. Is it possible to define this ratio according to the device type?

Comment: what is the problem ? Make PTM_RATIO as constant and change it according to device (e.g. [[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom])

Comment: But, wait a minute, if I make it a constant, then I won't be able to change it later. Constants are constants as their names imply. And besides that, I need to put the PTM_RATIO in one header file.

Comment: make it static instead of const

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BTW you can replace all the PTM_RATIO occurrences in your code with

`[Box2DHelper pixelsToMeterRatio]`

This way you can switch between Retina resolution and normal resolution without any problems.

Check out the file
http://subversion.assembla.com/svn/oiram/trunk/GoLeft/GoLeft/Box2DHelper.mm

To know about CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR  check out [When to use CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11200916/when-to-use-cc-content-scale-factor)

Update: E.g. to have different PTM for iPad

```
#define isIPad UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad 
#define PTM_RATIO (isIPad ? 64 : 32)
```

Comment: As you can see in the link you provided PTM_RATIO is set to 32. But 32 is not OK for iPADs.

Comment: that is kPointsToMeterRatio not pixel to meter

Comment: That works only for retina and non-retina display configurations. But screen size in iPad and iPhone is different. So fixed 32 won't help.

Comment: #define isIPad    UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad
#define PTM_RATIO         (isIPad ? 64 : 32)

Comment: Yeah, that's right.I was just looking for device determinator directive.